# WEIRD BEHAVIOUR of LIGHTBOXES

Tags: html, css, image, lightbox

I've just tried the [CSS code](https://codepen.io/ongtiffany/pen/BoOeQV) written by @ongtiffany on [codepen.io](https://codepen.io) about lightboxes.
The code is great, but if I use it on a standalone test (follows)

```html
   <body>
        <a class="lightbox" href="#first">
            <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1cKXuGQzX3t65NoYEKfuI4wBHwxUM9wjH"/>
        </a>
        <div class="lightbox-target" id="first">
            <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1cKXuGQzX3t65NoYEKfuI4wBHwxUM9wjH"/>
            <a class="lightbox-close" href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <a class="lightbox" href="#second">
            <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1kLe9YXiM2XdgwKkATwkhfk6kzdnKIefi"/>
        </a>
        <div class="lightbox-target" id="second">
            <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1kLe9YXiM2XdgwKkATwkhfk6kzdnKIefi"/>
            <a class="lightbox-close" href="#"></a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It leaves me a weird "_" symbol between the two pictures.

Can you see it? Any advice to eliminate it?

And one more question? What could it be a way to get a window closing by pressing the "ESC" key?

Comment: That's the text-decoration on the links

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
a.lightbox{
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

OUTPUT

[image]